# Sampling-based code profile or performance analysis for dotnet core program in Windows

Tags: .net-core

I am looking for how to do code profiling on a machine where Visual Studio cannot be installed.

In Linux, .net core (aka. dotnet core or CoreCLR) programs can be code-profiled with perf program. ([Link](https://codeblog.dotsandbrackets.com/profiling-net-core-app-linux/))

In Windows, I cannot find how to do the similar thing. I tried vsperf.exe, but it seems that it does not show the C# code.

[image]

Of course, I can use vsperf.exe for native (x86 or x64) program. It works correctly.

[image]

Is there any way to do sampling-based code profile or performance analysis for dotnet core program in Windows?